# Cannot resolve symbol on all of my code in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I uninstalled and re-installed android studio in order to try to fix some issue I had with it. It did not solve the issue but created another one (at least I think this is what created the new issue). I have 'Cannot resolve symbol' on all of my lines of code on another app. The first issue was on flutter app and the 'Cannot resolve symbol' issue is on a native app development (java).

[image]

I don't know if the issue with the native app is because of the reinstallation since I opened it after a long time I wans't on it. All I know to say is that I don't have the same issue on the kotlin code I use in my flutter app, and if I start a new project (which is automitically using kotlin) I also don't have this issue.

Even though the 'Cannot resolve symbol' issue, it lets me build the app. It does not luanch it on the device (it says "Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
Error while Launching activity"), but I can open the app manually on my phone after the build.

Any idea why this is happening and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. What causes both of the issues in is a CSV plugin for flutter I installed. Since I disabled the plugin and restart the android studio, everything is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

**Clean Project:**

1. Click on `Build` Menu.
2. Choose `Clean Project`.

**Clean Cache:**

3. Click on `File` Menu.
4. Choose `Invalidate Caches / Restart...`.
5. Click `Invalidate and Restart` button in the `Invalidate Cache` dialog box.

Comment: Check your SDK location

Comment: this happen after I upgrade to Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1
It's wasting time

Answer (score 0):

```
Click on File >> Close Project

Delete .idea folder in project Directory

Open Project again
```

Comment: while deleting  .idea folder your project in Android studio should be closed

Comment: Are you getting any completion help on typing names of any Android API class followed by dot(.) like Activity. ,  Fragment.   ....??

Comment: @WahdatKashmiri Yes I closed it

Comment: @gpl I am getting general suggestions (like "new"). Not something specific to the class.

Comment: have you checked your android SDK location? Is it targeting to right directory?